# Child Parent Context Save Conflicts

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

How are conflicts resolved when a child `NSManagedObjectContext` is saved and the changes are pushed to the parent `NSManagedObjectContext`?

For instance, lets say you are updating `NSManagedObject` `Person` by setting the attribute `age` to 18 on a child context with an `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` from data from a server. At the same time, the same `NSManagedObject` `Person` `age` attribute is updated to a value of 20 by the user on the parent `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

After both updates a save is called on the child context which propagates to the parent `NSManagedObjectContext`.

What is the value of age at this point? Does the child `NSManagedObjectContext` overwrite the parent `NSManagedObjectContext`? Do `NSMergePolicies` apply here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no conflict resolution when saving from a child to a parent.  The child always changes the parent, regardless of what values the parent has, or whether the parent has unsaved changes itself.

Furthermore, there is no merge policy or built-in other way to alter this behavior.

It is possible to write your own merge policy management, but it's a bit tricky.  You are probably better off just knowing the rules.